# Maintain output for ~3secs after losing input

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, automotive, 12v

I have a simple circuit in my car. A +12V signal wire that comes from the ignition is used to tell an amplifier to power on.

When +12V is present here, the amp turns on and is powered by a separate, higher rated +12V feed from the battery.

The issue is that my car has start stop technology, so when I roll up to lights, the engine dies, and when I pull away, it starts again.

The +12V signal is present when the engine is not running, but when the car starts itself, it drops to 0V for a couple of seconds, before returning. I can only assume this is because the car routes the current through the starter relay instead.

My question is this. Is there a means of maintaining that 12V signal at an output for a couple of seconds after the input goes off? It literally only needs to be a couple of seconds, the input is back before long. I was thinking some kind of capacitor bank?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Diode plus capacitors. Without the diode your capacitors help start the car. For calculations we need an estimate how much current your radio uses. Mine (4x50W) I just today found out is specified as 10A max.

Comment: Thing is, the amp shouldn't really pull any current down that cable, it's merely to act as a signal for a relay.

Comment: The rail drops to zero so the brownout (due to cranking) does not affect anything on the switched system; a controlled drop and re-power will simply force equipment on the switched system to do a cold start and reset.

Comment: The car has a start-stop... no-one would buy a car with a stereo, GPS and computer which hard reboots at every traffic light! I highly doubt that it browns out to a low enough voltage to bother OP's sound system... so let's clear this up: Jacob, can you measure the +12V which supplies your amp while the car cranks? I mean, not the line that you already know goes to zero, but the main power supply.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the car's headunit does not shut off, just the aftermarket amp in the boot. I had assumed that the headunit was switched by the ignition but perhaps it is on a different circuit.

Comment: I will measure it when I get home from work and let you know.

Comment: I notice that the [loom that goes into the head unit](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=medianav+connector&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=V9i77D8-RLaWvM%253A%252CacxNiL-Qh1sdjM%252C_&usg=__o-sZgkX2cN9G8OUxU5HYFac8eWE%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6hNCz0sbaAhWKIsAKHQTpAd8Q9QEIKzAA#imgrc=V9i77D8-RLaWvM:) has two wake up wires, ACC and IGN. I assume I'm hooked into one or the other spurring straight from the ignition switch. Maybe I'll try and locate the other.

Comment: @peufeu The main power supply sits at 12.6V when the engine is off and 14.4V when the engine is running. I assume this is due to the alternator now charging the battery.

Comment: Yeah, these voltages are normal, so what is the voltage when the starter motor cranks? Also maybe one of the ACC ("accessory?") and IGN ("ignition?") wires already does what you want...